# Custom product type only in index price table after reindex of index price in index management

Tags: php, magento

I created my own product type and want to index the price but this only happens after ive ran the reindex from index management.

I have added an indexer (my product is similar to a grouped one).
The file looks like this

```
 <?php

    class Mymodule_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Mymodule extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default {
        /*
          /**
         * Reindex temporary (price result data) for all products
         *
         * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Grouped
         */

        public function reindexAll() {
            $this->useIdxTable(true);
            $this->beginTransaction();
            try {
                $this->_prepareMymodulePriceData();
                $this->commit();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->rollBack();
                throw $e;
            }
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Reindex temporary (price result data) for defined product(s)
         *
         * @param int|array $entityIds
         * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Grouped
         */
        public function reindexEntity($entityIds) {
            $this->_prepareMymoduleData($entityIds);
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Calculate minimal and maximal prices for Grouped products
         * Use calculated price for relation products
         *
         * @param int|array $entityIds  the parent entity ids limitation
         * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Grouped
         */
        protected function _prepareMymodulePriceData($entityIds = null) {
            $write = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
            $table = $this->getIdxTable();

            $select = $write->select()
                    ->from(array('e' => $this->getTable('catalog/product')), 'entity_id')
                    ->joinLeft(
                            array('l' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_link')), 'e.entity_id = l.product_id AND l.link_type_id=' . Mymodule_Model_Product_Type_Link::LINK_TYPE_Mymodule, array())
                    ->join(
                    array('cg' => $this->getTable('customer/customer_group')), '', array('customer_group_id'));
            $this->_addWebsiteJoinToSelect($select, true);
            $this->_addProductWebsiteJoinToSelect($select, 'cw.website_id', 'e.entity_id');
            $maxCheckSql = $write->getCheckSql('le.required_options = 0', 'i.max_price', 0);
            $select->columns('website_id', 'cw')
                    ->joinLeft(
                            array('le' => $this->getTable('catalog/product')), 'le.entity_id = l.linked_product_id', array())
                    ->joinLeft(
                            array('i' => $table), 'i.entity_id = l.linked_product_id AND i.website_id = cw.website_id'
                            . ' AND i.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id', array(
                        'tax_class_id' => $this->_getReadAdapter()
                        ->getCheckSql('MIN(i.tax_class_id) IS NULL', '0', 'MIN(i.tax_class_id)'),
                        'price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL'),
                        'final_price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL'),
                        'min_price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(' . $maxCheckSql . ')'),
                        'max_price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(' . $maxCheckSql . ')'),
                        'tier_price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL')
                    ))
                    ->group(array('e.entity_id', 'cg.customer_group_id', 'cw.website_id'))
                    ->where('e.type_id=?', $this->getTypeId());
            if (!is_null($entityIds)) {
                $select->where('l.product_id IN(?)', $entityIds);
            }

            /**
             * Add additional external limitation
             */
            Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_prepare_index_select', array(
                'select' => $select,
                'entity_field' => new Zend_Db_Expr('e.entity_id'),
                'website_field' => new Zend_Db_Expr('cw.website_id'),
                'store_field' => new Zend_Db_Expr('cs.store_id')
            ));
            $query = $select->insertFromSelect($table);
            $write->query($query);
            return $this;

        }

}
```

And my config looks like this:

```
    <product>
        <type>
            <Mymoduletranslate="label" module="Mymodule">
                <label>Mymodule</label>
                <model>Mymodule/product_type_Mymodule</model>
                <price_model>Mymodule/product_price</price_model>
                <composite>1</composite>
                <index_priority>15</index_priority>
                <allow_product_types>
                    <simple/>
                    <virtual/>
                </allow_product_types>
                <price_indexer>Mymodule/product_indexer_price_Mymodule</price_indexer>
            </Mymodule>
        </type>
    </product>
```

When i mage log the file it is also ran when i save the product. My guess is that I am missing some vital part to make the whole thing work :(

Any help on this is welcome.